# My textbox in P5 won't allow me to input anything?

Tags: javascript, input, text, textbox

I'm trying to create an input-based typing game, but my textbox won't work. How do I fix this? [Here's](https://editor.p5js.org/parkzar/full/gDeZDQ4O3) the link to the entire game, but the issues are in the file "screen1.js". Any help is appreciated! I know it's an input problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

EDIT: I know it's a very poorly made game. It's for a project.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

[[image: HTML source code of your game1]

I think something went wrong, because there is a lot of inputs there on your page...

Comment: That's so weird. I don't know how to fix that.